# Exclude an input on form dirty

Tags: html

I have a form in which there is a checkbox per line, and I use it to make a selection of product lines.

If I make a line selection, the form detects that there has been a change. But the data has not changed, it is just a selection.

Is there a way to exclude an input from dirty?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include some relevant code as part of a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can better understand what you're asking.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.